# Ошибки ArrayList, странное поведение contains

Tags: java, android

Странное поведение `contains`, после долгой отладки я заметил то что он практически не работает, всегда возвращает `false` Вот код:

```
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> cacheTemp=null;
//ФУНКЦИИ СОЗДАНИЯ Array (к вопросу не относится)
```

Дальше идут простые функции

```
public static boolean getBoolean(int comnat){
    //Если индекс записи существует должно вернутся true, но всегда возвращается false.
    if(cacheTemp.contains(comnat))return true;
    return false;
}

public static boolean setArrayList(int comnat, ArrayList<String> temp){
    //МАССИВ КОМНАТ
    if(getBoolean(comnat)) {
        cacheTemp.set(comnat, temp);
    }else cacheTemp.add(comnat, temp);


    if(getBoolean(comnat)) {
        Voider.log("setArrayList", "true", "e"); //НЕ ВЫПОЛНЯЕТСЯ, ПО ЛОГИКЕ ДОЛЖЕН, СОЗДАН ДЛЯ ТЕСТА

    }

    return true;
}
```

Шлю я аргументы простые,

```
ArrayList<String> temp=new ArrayList<String>();
setArrayList(0, temp);
```

и так далее

Comment: ничё не понятно, но наверно надо указать ArrayList<Integer> при создании

Comment: Хм, что вам не понятно? В строчке Странное поведение contains, после долгой отладки я заметил то что он практически не работает, всегда возвращает false.. P.S Я инициализирую когда надо  array list, и вопрос был не почему падает приложение( если там null) а почему возвращается false на contains

Comment: Пробовал что-то типо этого     public static boolean getBoolean(int comnat){
        //КОМНАТА СУЩЕСТВУЕТ?

        return cacheTemp.get(comnat) != null;
    } но падение

Comment: почитайте javadoc по методу contains. Он делает совершенно не то, что вы от него ожидаете. Он проверяет, содержится ли переданный объект в списке. У вас список из арейлистов. Вы проверяете, содержится ли int в массиве из аррейлистов. Что бы вы туда не передали, ответ всегда будет false, так как int по определению не может содержаться в массиве из ArrayList<String>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Вроде работает,
>
> ```
> public static boolean getBoolean(int comnat){
>     //КОМНАТА СУЩЕСТВУЕТ?
>     return comnat >=0 && comnat < cacheTemp.size() && cacheTemp.get(comnat) != null;
> }
> ```
>
> правильно или нет я не знаю точно, но работает

Это было очень давно, вопрос старый, не рекомендую это использовать слишком медленно. ArrayList при использовании функции get выдаст исключение если вы вышли за пределы массива.

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(1);

try{
    System.err.println(list.get(2));
}catch(java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
    e.printStackTrace(); //выбросить ошибку в error поток
    //что делать если вы вышли за пределы массива
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот тут вы не верно используете contains, он проверяет на вхождение объект, т.е. ищет в коллекции элемент (integer) а у вас там ArrayList'ы лежат

```
public static boolean getBoolean(int comnat){
    //КОМНАТА СУЩЕСТВУЕТ?
    if(cacheTemp.contains(comnat))return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Она должна проверить существует ли вообще запись (в которой обьект) в списке ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>, но всегда false

Comment: А, тоесть он проверяет существование содержимого, а как тогда проверить существование элемента?

Comment: Что бы узнать размер  ArrayList используйте метод size()

Comment: Элементы могут быть в разнобой, тоесть 1 обьект 3 обьект 6 обьект

Comment: А зачем такая кучерявая логика?

Comment: За тем, что присутствуют фитчи delete, тоесть элемент может иметь null. Когда вы удаляете файл из файловой системы ntfs, файловая система фрагментируется, и на месте удаленного файла появляется кусок свободного места (в данном случае в моем массиве это null) и вы хотите сказать что создатели ntfs были кучерявыми и туту?

Comment: как будто вы в первом посте описали что это и зачем

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо переписать функцию следующим образом

```
public static boolean getBoolean(int comnat){
    return cacheTemp.size() > comnat;
}
```

Comment: Элементы могут быть в разнобой, тоесть 1 обьект 3 обьект 6 обьект

Comment: Почему вы решили использовать ArrayList а не обычный двумерный массив?

Comment: За тем что он удобнее, и он подходит мне, +у меня динамичное создание обьектов а переопределять массив каждый раз неизвестно как, мне просто не хочется на себя брать эту ересь... Зачем изобретать изобретенное?)